# Masking a sensitive column in a table for different users groups in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using sql server 2014 version. I have a sensitive information in a column. Assume it has phone numbers that contains following values.

```
+------------------------+
| Private_Mobile_Number  |
+------------------------+
|             1234567890 |
|             0987654321 |
+------------------------+
```

Now for example I have two user groups based on their rights as below and also my expectation about the visibility of the column to different user groups

1. **Data writing users** - who can work on database elements like create, drop etc.

   ```
                 No value should be masked. Values must be displayed as it is.
   ```
2. **Data reading users** - who can only view the data

   ```
                 Last five digits must be masked. example: ***12345xxxxx***
   ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For the users who have rights for working on the database elements should be able to view the column values in table without masking. 

For the users who have only read only access on db, the last 5 digits of the value in the column should be masked

Comment: Create a view masking the last 5 digits and GRANT SELECT to the restricted users on it... and obviously DENY SELECT on all other objects.